# What is the maximum payload weight for create 2/can I use old create accessories with the Create 2?

Tags: mobile-robot, irobot-create

I'm attempting to build a heavy platform on the Create 2 but am worried about weight on the platform.  What is the maximum weight for the platform and is there an optimum?

I have an old create and want to know if any of my existing cables and accessories can be used with the new Create 2?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you keep the payload in the bin or near the top of the robot, 9 kg is a safe amount of max payload weight on a flat floor. Create doesn't dynamically balance, so having the weight in both a statically and a dynamically stable location is important. We've also provided files for printing a bin with a caster, in the case that you find your robot is constantly doing wheelies. :)

Almost all existing cables and accessories should be supported in both directions, as long as they use the 7-pin serial connector. One of our goals was to allow current parts and accessories to stay useful! Unfortunately, there is no 25-pin payload connector, so any accessories which used that will not work. Finally, the original Create's dock is not compatible. The good news is that the Create 2 will avoid its predecessor's dock, and we ship every Create 2 with a new-style dock.

Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.

Comment: As a side note, please stick with the metric system. The imperial system is not understood almost anywhere in the world and it is not recognized by scientists either.

Comment: I'm not a scientist; I'm an engineer! ;) Point well taken; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Only an American Engineer would say that @Steve *8') Even in the UK where we use miles on our road signs, and buy milk by the pint, Engineers still use SI units for projects.

Comment: Incidentally, thanks for your help answering Roomba and Create questions. I spotted that Create support pages were directing people here, I hadn't spotted that you were also supporting the community we are building here.

Comment: We normally use SI units here, too; it just happens that the weights that are commonly available in the U.S. are Imperial, and before I answered the question I wanted to verify theoretical information with some solid test data. (Let's blame my original post in pounds on possibly having a pint or two before answering, shall we? :) As far as helping to answer Roomba and Create questions here, I can tell you that we are very passionate about encouraging communities like this one, because they are exactly the communities we want to be a part of as robotics engineers!